# location.reload() doesn't update page with new data in Chrome after JQuery Post

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

After posting successfully data with `jQuery.post()` to the ajax.php I would like to refresh page to show the updated record. But… `location.reload()` **does not update the page data from `.post()`** in Chrome. It only updates with browser refresh (F5).

I've tried:

1. window.location.reload();
2. window.location.reload(true);
3. location.reload();
4. location.reload(true);
5. document.location.reload();
6. document.location.reload(true);
7. **window.location.refresh();**

And it seems it is an *enduring Chrome issue*: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6429

How can I overcome this bug?

### HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>First Item</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- new record after reload goes here -->
</table>
```

### JavaScript:

```
function addItem() {
  var data_item_name = "data to be posted and shown after reload";
  jQuery.post("ajax.php",
     {item_name: data_item_name},
     function(data){
        console.log(data);
     }
  );
  window.location.reload();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you further define _"browser refresh"_. Unless, you're clearing your cache, pressing `<F5>` to reload the page or using `location.reload();` should have the same effect as far as I know. Just curious, but why are you reloading after using an AJAX post? The whole point of AJAX is to avoid reloading the page. If you're going to reload the page anyway, you might as well do a regular form submit with a post back.

Comment: "Browser refresh" = F5. It is a JQuery overlay Dialog entry (for convenience) and instead of appending/modifying the page contents with JQuery I need to reload page.

Comment: Also circumstances does not allow to write code for post back.

Comment: It seems your line containing location reload not executing /firing. If you provide your ajax code snippet, we can track the issue.

Comment: I hope this will add more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not perform the reload until after the post is complete.

```
$.post(url, data, function () {
    // reload here!
});
```

Comment: This is a clean solution! Thank you. P.S. And you were right, setTimeout() is buggy idea:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Hope it works for you, if not, good luck finding the solution! ;)

Comment: Ups! Sorry. Did you try to user something else than jQuery to reload?

Comment: No. The functions are written in JQuery.